# JMeter dynamic http request parameters from CSV

Tags: jmeter

I want to HTTP request with dynamic parameters, so I created a CSV Data Set Config. This is a CSV Data Set Config example:

**CSV DATA SET CONFIG**

```
"lat";"lng"
40.9912941561618;28.7894749639963
41.0824834;28.9850201
41.0611814136864;28.030526752118
41.0001116337;29.1471918672
40.9840449469281;28.868293762207
41.0062257041343;28.6599397659302
40.9870953373281;28.8735637664795
40.9842483906616;28.8679887067701
```

**HTTP REQUEST**

Server name is example.com. Delimeter is ;.

Dynamic parameter path is v1/ej/log/geojson?lat=${lat}&lng=${lat};

CSV Data Set Config [image]

[image: HTTP REQUEST]

When I sent request it doesn't set the parameters. How I can do ?

Comment: What's your jmeter version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)  is by default a Comma Separated Values. In your file it's `;` Separated, so you need to define Delimiter as `;`.

Also remove quotes for first line with variable names:

```
 lat;lng
```

And make sure you set the flag

> Use first line as Variable Names
>
> Ignore first line of CSV file, it will only be used used if Variable Names is not empty, if Variable Names is empty the first line must contain the headers.

Values are stored as JMeter variables and used as: `${lat}` so your path should be

```
 v1/ej/log/geojson?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried as you said I got an error. Error is java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 53: https://example.com/v1/ej/log/geojson?lat=${lat}lng=${lng}

Comment: Did you changed all ? can you show updated CSV and configuration? also I have a missing `&`, path should end with `lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}`

Comment: Yes I tried as you said now. Error is java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 53: https://example.com/v1/ej/log/geojson?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}  cvs data for example lat;lng
40.9912941561618;28.7894749639963 and I changed delimiter to ;. Variable names are lat;lng

Comment: Variable names should be empty

Comment: Yes I did but  didn't send any request. I edited my question

Comment: @Hermes I see you have old version, so I suggest you remove the first line of your CSV file and set in CSV Data Set Config Variable names: `lat,lng`

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me :)